# Rewriting the trigonometric representation of a stochastic process into exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, stochastic-processes, exponential-function

Fenton and Griffiths (2008) in *Risk Assessment in Geotechnical Engineering* give the following representation of a stochastic process:

$$Z(x_j) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} A_k \cos(\omega_k x_j) + B_k \sin(\omega_k x_j) $$

This can be rewritten as:

$$Z(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} (A_k - iB_k)e^{i\omega_kx_j}$$

Can anyone explain how to go from the first equation to the second? Do any assumptions/conclusions need to be made to do this?

My attempt:

\begin{align}
A_k \cos(\omega_k x_j) + B_k \sin(\omega_k x_j) &= A_k\left(\frac{e^{i\omega_kt_j} + e^{-i\omega_kt_j}}{2}\right) + B_k\left(\frac{e^{i\omega_kt_j} - e^{-i\omega_kt_j}}{2}\right)\\
&= (A_k + B_k)\left(\frac{e^{i\omega_kt_j}}{2}\right) + (A_k - B_k)\left(\frac{e^{-i\omega_kt_j}}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Actually, "[t]his can be rewritten as"
$$Z(x) =\Re\left( \sum_{k=0}^{N} (A_k - iB_k)e^{i\omega_kx}\right)$$

Comment: @Did. Thanks for your comment. Can you give the steps from the 1st equation in my question to your equation?

Comment: $$\Re((A-iB)(\cos t+i\sin t))=A\cos t+B\sin t$$

Comment: @Did Thanks for the help my dude.